# How to play BBC 6 music on rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

How do I get BBC 6 Music radio station to play on Rhythmbox?

I get the following pop-up message:

```
Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type:     
text/html decoder
```

and now I am stuck.

Yes, I am a newbie, I much prefer Ubuntu but I do struggle some of the time....(some?)

And what is a tag?

Answer (score 2):

After adding the station in Music > New Internet Radio Station, and trying to play it, `Rhythmbox` should prompt you to install the necessary packages. This is what happened  for me and then 6Music played.

If Rhythmbox doesn't prompt you to install the necessary packages, I got 6Music playing by installing the following additional packages on 12.04- the packages names might differ on 12.10. This is the list that `Rhythmbox` recommended, but not all are probably necessary:

```
sudo apt-get install libcdaudio1 libflite1 libgme0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 libmimic0 libofa0 libopenspc0 libslv2-9 libspandsp2 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libzbar0 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
```

The `gstreamer` plugins are probably the most important, but installing the whole lot of recommended packages did get 6Music streaming.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm:

you opened rhythmbox
clicked on radio
clicked the add button
pasted the link http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r6.asx into the box
clicked on radio again and selected the link?

if you did this and got the error then try  reinstall of the app.

ensure you have all your settings stored as I can't remember if you'll lose them.

sudo apt-get install --reinstall rhythmbox

then add the link again.

To change the title of the station to a recognizable one, right click on the title and click ‘Properties‘.

Hope this helps.